# Angular Mat-Icon shows Text only(not the img)

Tags: angular, angular-material, icons, styles, mat

I have imported the mat icon module.

Also, my `<link_href=...>` already changed in the index html. + Import indigo-pink.css on the s.css

May I ask some assistance please

```js
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';'''


imports: [
  ...
  MatIconModule
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the styles link?

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

Sample with minimum imports for icons:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-hw66ra?file=src/index.html

Comment: The styles link were like that by default

Comment: Have you ever checked the stackblitz i attached? Or can you reproduce the issue on stackblitz?

Comment: @huanfeng thank you so much for the example. In my case, the problem was a style added to the angular.json referring material icons that shouldn't be there.